Can't plot on top of existing figure
I have a custom-made plotting function com_snaps(), that I don't want to change, and I want to call it twice. The issue is that I never get to see the plot resulting from the first call:
# snaps_to_plot2 is the first plot 
# snaps_to_plot is the second plot 
colors2 = ['black']
colors = ['green']
linewidths2 = [2]
linewidths = [1]

fig, ax1, ax2 = com_snaps(grid_x2, grid_y2, snaps_to_plot2, inds_to_plot, labels, colors2, linewidths2)
fig, ax1, ax2 = com_snaps(grid_x, grid_y, snaps_to_plot, inds_to_plot, labels, colors, linewidths) 
ax1.legend(), ax2.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('figure.png', dpi=300)


def com_snaps(grid_x, grid_y, snaps_to_plot, inds_to_plot, labels, colors, linewidths):
  fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
  for i, snaps in enumerate(snaps_to_plot):
    plot_snaps(grid_x, grid_y, snaps, inds_to_plot,
               #label=labels[i],
               fig_ax=(fig, ax1, ax2),
               color=colors[i],
               linewidth=linewidths[i])
  return fig, ax1, ax2

where plot_snaps() only uses plotting commands of the type ax1.plot(), ax2.plot().
I have tried everything, plt.show() in between, after, etc. Is it the issue here that I am overwriting the figure?

What IDE are you using? Do you see any figures?

I save the figures to a .png and I can only see the second plot. I don't know how to fix the code to not overwrite the first (the first call to com_snaps())

Are you saving them with different names?

I edited the post - I save like this: plt.savefig('figure.png', dpi=300)

You're only saving the second figure.

Firstly, you're only calling the save function once and it's on the second figure (since that's the active figure when you call the function). Secondly, you're overwriting the fig, ax1, and ax2 variables when you call the second plot function. That's fine assuming all you want to do is save the plots since you can simply save the first plot before generating the second one. Be sure to give them unique names so you don't overwrite the first png with the second one.
fig, ax1, ax2 = com_snaps(grid_x2, grid_y2, snaps_to_plot2, inds_to_plot, labels, colors2, linewidths2)
ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("figure1.png", dpi=300)

fig, ax1, ax2 = com_snaps(grid_x, grid_y, snaps_to_plot, inds_to_plot, labels, colors, linewidths) 
ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("figure2.png", dpi=300)


What I am looking for is actually only one figure with the two plots!

My question was rather why does the first plot get deleted when the second plot is drawn? Is there a way to keep the first plot in the figure?

Does my updated answer clarify things?

Nope. That code snippet produces 2 figures with two independent plots and what I want is the two plots on top of each other and save it as 1 figure. In MATLAB you would do "hold on" ....

Oh. Then you'll have to edit your comm_snaps function since it currently creates a new figure every time you call it. But you said you don't want to edit that code. You can't do it unless you edit it.

@Andrea Do you still need help with this?
